# The view polls.views.forms didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, forms

Why am I seing this and my views returns a HttpResponse object.

This is my view

```
def forms(request):
    from forms import SearchForm
     """process the form"""

    if request.method == 'GET':

        #create a ew form and populate it with the data
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)

        #validate the data
        if form.is_valid():
        #process the data in cleaned_data attribute

            name = form.cleaned_data['name']

            return HttpResponse("Received this word: {}".format(name))

    else:
        form = SearchForm()

        #return this
        return render(request, 'polls/form.html', {'form' : form})
```

As i can see, My view return a HttpResponse and on the branch condition it returns a render. My other views works the same

Comment: So what does it return if the form is *not* valid? (And note that your outer if statement is pointless; the method will always be GET if you're not sending your form via POST.)

Comment: Actually that was the problem. The misplaced if statement. But then that creates another tragedy. it does not return the HttpResponse, Its giving me a blank page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code fell into the if/else branch you didn't cover. Take another look carefully, you code would return `None` if the statement `if form.is_valid()` failed. What I usually do is:

```
def forms(request):
    from forms import SearchForm
     """process the form"""

    form = SearchForm(request.GET or None)
    # validate the data
    if form.is_valid():
        # process the data in cleaned_data attribute
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        return HttpResponse("Received this word: {}".format(name))

    return render(request, 'polls/form.html', {'form' : form})
```

If your `GET` data is in compliance with the form, you would get into `is_valid()` branch and return `HttpResponse`. Otherwise you either render a form that has error message or a blank form, both situation would result in `return render(request, 'polls/form.html', {'form' : form})`.